# Keeping mail dry in locking mailbox?

Tags: weather-resistant, mailbox

I'm thinking about installing a locking mailbox.  My main concern after reading online reviews of locking mailbox models is not security but rather mail getting wet.  Seems to be a recurring complaint on every model I read about.  I'm in western Oregon where it is constantly raining and wet.

Anyone faced this problem and solved it?  Or tips on preventing it?  Curious for any tips/advice.  Thanks

Comment: Keeping the inside of your mailbox dry, probably has a lot to do with which way the opening is facing. Can you face it away from the prevailing winds?

Comment: Build a small "shed" out of cedar or redwood over the box to keep direct blowing rain off of the box. At least build a roof over it.

Comment: and make sure there is a drainage hole, perhaps with a wire mesh to lift the letters off the bottom so the paper won't have a chance to wick up any water that is running off.